# No EntityManager with actual transaction when publish event to Saga

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, event-sourcing, saga, axon

I'm using "axon 4.0.3 + Spring Boot 2 + Spring Data (PostgreSQL)" default configuration.

Having published event to the EventStore and waiting for it to be catched by @SagaEventHandler I received the following exception:

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with
>   actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably
>   process 'persist' call    at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:292)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_191]   at
>   org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.jpa.JpaEventStorageEngine.appendEvents(JpaEventStorageEngine.java:276)
>   ~[axon-eventsourcing-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]     at
>   org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.AbstractEventStorageEngine.appendEvents(AbstractEventStorageEngine.java:98)
>   ~[axon-eventsourcing-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]

What additional configuration is required for the EventStore to handle this case?

PS. Adding @Transactional on the method solves this problem, but i dont understand why this is neccessary.

Minimum code example (the following endpoint 127.0.0.1:8080/1 is worked but the other one 127.0.0.1:8080/1 is not):

```
@SpringBootApplication
class TestAxonApplication

class UserId(val userId: String = IdentifierFactory.getInstance().generateIdentifier()) : Serializable

class TestCommand(@TargetAggregateIdentifier val userId: UserId)

class TestedEvent(val userId: UserId)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<TestAxonApplication>(*args)
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping
class Controller(var commandGateway: CommandGateway, var eventStore: EventStore) {

    @GetMapping("/1")
    fun done(): UserId? {
        return commandGateway.sendAndWait<UserId>(TestCommand(UserId()))
    }

    @GetMapping("/2")
    fun failure() {
        eventStore.publish(
                GenericEventMessage.asEventMessage<Void>(
                        TestedEvent(UserId())
                )
        )
    }

}

@Aggregate
class User() {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private lateinit var userId: UserId

    @CommandHandler
    constructor(cmd: TestCommand) : this() {
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(TestedEvent(cmd.userId))
    }

    @EventHandler
    fun on(event: TestedEvent) {
        this.userId = event.userId
    }

}

@Saga
@ProcessingGroup("mySaga")
class MySaga {

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "userId")
    fun start(event: TestedEvent) {
        println("DONE ${event.userId.userId}")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

the difference between the calls, is that one goes through the Command Bus, while the other one skips that and published to the event bus directly. By default, a `TransactionManager` is configured on the Command Bus. However, it is not the case on the event bus.

This means you're publishing an event without a Transaction being active. Hibernate doesn't like that.

The solution is to put `@Transactional` on your endpoint, to ensure a transaction is active when storing events.

Comment: I actually think Axon should be able to cope with this approach somewhat better. I've created an issue to improve transaction management for these cases: https://github.com/AxonFramework/AxonFramework/issues/1035

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forget to setup the command bus in order to allows the transaction management. Add it like the below example and it will work:

```
@Bean
public CommandBus commandBus(TransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new SimpleCommandBus(transactionManager, NoOpMessageMonitor.INSTANCE);
}
```

**Update**

My fault, first of all I'm use to work with Axon 3.3 (not the lastest ones) and I was thinking you was using a custom configuration for the event store.

Axon spring boot by default use inmemory event store and that is why if you don't define a custom one the transactions will not work.

This is what is missing in your configurarion:

```
@Bean
public EventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine(EntityManagerProvider entityManagerProvider, TransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new JpaEventStorageEngine(entityManagerProvider, transactionManager);
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
}
```

´´´

This is a simple example i did for other proposals and it works perfectly.

**To keep in mind**

Other interesting point is that you must define the aggregate repositories because Axon tries to look for a repository which match with the defined aggregate.

```
@Bean
public Repository<User> documentAggregateRepository(EventStore eventStore) {
    return new EventSourcingRepository<>(User.class, eventStore);
}
```

The same for sagas, you must register them or the saga will never be trigger

```
// remember to call the method sagaName + Configuration
// or you must set up the @Saga configurationBean name pointing this method
@Bean
public SagaConfiguration<MySaga> mySagaConfiguration() {
    return SagaConfiguration.subscribingSagaManager(MySaga.class);
}
```

In this example is event sourcing but if you are interesting on legacy migrations maybe you will use GenericJpaRepository during the migration process (if you need an example just let me know).

HTH.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. In debug mode i see that JpaEventStorageEngine is successfully configured in JpaEventStoreAutoConfiguration